What is the significance of non-regular or non-hyperregular Lagrangians in mechanical systems?
From Abraham & Marsden:

For a manifold $Q$ and a Lagrangian $L:TQ\to \mathbb{R}$, the fiber derivative $\mathbb FL:TQ\to T^*Q:w_q\mapsto DL_q(w_q)$ (where $L_q$ is the restriction of $L$ to the fiber over $q\in Q$ is said to be regular if at all points of $x\in T^*Q$, it holds that $T_y(\mathbb FL)$ is surjective for all $y=\mathbb FL^{-1}(x)$ and hyperregular if $\mathbb{F}L$ is a diffeomorphism.

I've read a few papers about mechanics that make the assumption of regularity. Would it be reasonable for an author to make the assumption of hyperregularity, or would that exclude too many situations?
(also, I'm sort of having trouble visualizing mechanical systems for which regularity holds but hyperregularity doesn't...)
